# selectively enabling a test program if Python is available - automake

Tags: python, portability, automake

I've got a program that's written in C, built using automake/autoconf, and has two test suites.  One is a unit test suite also written in C; the other is end-to-end and is (currently) written in Python.  I want "make check" to run the unit tests always, and the end-to-end tests only if Python is installed.  This is what I have now:

```
TESTS = unittests
if HAVE_PYTHON
TESTS += tester.py
tester_py_SOURCES = src/test/tester.py.in

tester.py: src/test/tester.py.in Makefile
        $(SED) -e 's,[@]PYTHON[@],$(PYTHON),' < $< > $@
        chmod +x $@
endif
```

`HAVE_PYTHON` is set by the configure script with

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON([2.6],, [:])
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_PYTHON], [test "$PYTHON" != ":"])
```

This works correctly on Unix, but blows up with "no rule to make tester.py.exe" on Windows. Also, the copy-and-substitute technique for getting the `#!` line right means I can't break up the test suite into multiple modules.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `_SOURCES` for compiled things only, so that's why it'a adding `$(EXEEXT)`. Try this:

```
TESTS = unittests
if HAVE_PYTHON
TESTS += tester.py
# Possibly use += here depending on the rest of your Makefile.am
check_SCRIPTS = tester.py
# I added $(srcdir) here so VPATH builds still work.
tester.py: $(srcdir)/src/test/tester.py.in Makefile
        $(SED) -e 's,[@]PYTHON[@],$(PYTHON),' < $< > $@
        chmod +x $@
endif
```

Is there any reason you don't just do the substitution via `configure.ac`?

```
AS_IF([test "$PYTHON" != ":"], [AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/test/tester.py])])
```

This will remake the script using `config.status` and autogenerate rebuild rules.

**EDIT 1:**

If what you really want to do is run the python tester script as part of `make check`, I'd do this:

```
check-local:
if HAVE_PYTHON
        $(PYTHON) $(srcdir)/src/test/tester.py
endif
```

(I put the `check-local` outside the `if HAVE_PYTHON` so that you can define other commands to run as part of `check-local`, if needed.)

You might prefer writing this, instead:

```
check-local:
        test "$(PYTHON)" != ":" && $(PYTHON) $(srcdir)/src/test/tester.py
```

See [extending](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Extending.html) in the automake manual.

Comment: `check_SCRIPTS`, of course, I shoulda thought of that.  As for the other, I thought you couldn't put `AC_CONFIG_FILES` inside an `AS_IF`, but anyway that wouldn't solve the problem of having to put everything in one giant file contra proper Python style.  What I really want here is a way to get the `check-TESTS` target to run '`$(PYTHON) $(srcdir)/src/test/tester.py`' instead of just '`./tester.py`'. (I may eventually give up and do a wrapper script, but I'm avoiding that because then I have to deal with more Windows crap.)

Comment: Yep, check-local seems to be the way to go.  Thanks.